# CentOS webmail setup using Windows Server DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, email-server, centos7

I'm having problems configuring CentOS7 to host as a mail server using Windows Server as a DNS, and cannot figure out where the problem is. The mail server and windows server are connected to a centOS setup as a router. Below are the iptables rules for both centOS outer and linux server

Linux Server

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
11307 7356K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    1    52 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:22
   21  1392 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 14630 packets, 3635K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
[root@az-ls13 tcattral]#
```

Linux Router

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 29 packets, 2088 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
54745   45M ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
  195 14820 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp spt:123
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:2113
   10   520 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
 6277 1270K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       168.63.129.16        0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:53
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp spt:53
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:53

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 154 packets, 8176 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
22786 4584K ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       172.16.13.4          0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:3389
22527 1460K ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            172.16.13.4          tcp dpt:3389
16783 1041K ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
10392 1559K ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:22
   33  1971 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
   16  1068 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:80
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 21,9990:10000
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport sports 21,9990:10000
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            172.16.13.4          tcp dpt:53
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       172.16.13.4          0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:53
  384 27511 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            172.16.13.4          udp dpt:53
  384 61432 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       172.16.13.4          0.0.0.0/0            udp spt:53
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            172.16.13.5          tcp spt:25 dpt:25
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            172.16.13.5          tcp spt:143 dpt:143
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            172.16.13.5          tcp spt:3306 dpt:3306

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 7294 packets, 1249K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
56429   17M ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            168.63.129.16
```

postfix/main.cf configuration

mydomain = mail.tcattral.com
myorigin = $mydomain
inet_interfaces = all
mydestination = $mydomain, $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
mailbox_command = /usr/libexec/dovecot/dovecot -lda -f "$SENDER" -a "$RECIPIENT"

dovecot config

/dovecot/dovecot.conf
protocols = imap

/dovecot/conf.d/10-ssl.conf
ssl = yes

/dovecot/conf.d/10-auth.conf
disable_plaintext_auth = no

/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir

[image: DNS Records on Windows Server]

[image: ifcfg-eth0 configuration]

Windows Client with Thunderbird network config

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : az-wc13
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Hyper-V Network Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-0D-3A-1C-8D-02
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::c8e5:ad5e:1856:b43d%5(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.13.4(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.13.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 100666682
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-27-B4-7E-5C-00-0D-3A-1C-8D-02
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 172.16.13.4
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Windows Server Network Config

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : az-ws13
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Hyper-V Network Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-0D-3A-16-94-72
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::848d:f887:5e5:7c68%6(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.16.13.4(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 172.16.13.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 100666682
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-27-B2-C9-C1-00-0D-3A-16-94-72
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 172.16.13.4
                                       8.8.8.8
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

[image: Topology]

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: When trying to setup Thunderbird it cannot find the server

Comment: What server can't it find? Did you actually put a record for it in your DNS?

Comment: Thunderbird cannot find the Linux server, I have an A record for it called az-ls13 pointing to the IP address of the server. A CNAME record called mail that points to the az-ls13.tcattral.com and an MX record where the FQDN is tcattral.com the FQDN of the mail server is mail.tcattral.com

Comment: Eh? I can't find az-ls13.tcattral.com or mail.tcattral.com in the DNS. Exactly how did you create these records?

Comment: DNS records are created on the windows server through DNS tool

Comment: In the first screenshot in my question above, they're the 3rd, 6th, and 8th record

Comment: OK, that looks like a private network somewhere. Is your machine running Thunderbird actually on that network? Is it getting DNS from that Windows server, **not from the public Internet**?

Comment: Yes it is a private network, the windows client, windows server, linux server and Linux router are setup using the windows server as the DNS

Comment: Please show the networking configuration of the machine running Thunderbird.

Comment: I just added the windows client and server network configuration to the question above

Comment: Your Windows client isn't even on the same network. You should establish basic connectivity first.

Comment: There is connectivity between the windows client, windows server, linux server. I've included a picture of the network topology above

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem in iptables rules that was preventing apache, imap, smtp and mysql.